# How to convert integers to their word representation?

Tags: ruby

Please, tell me the function in Ruby which can do the below task:

- "0" should give me text "zero"
- "5" should give me text "five"
- "6" should give me text "six"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like the [`numbers_and_words`](https://github.com/kslazarev/numbers_and_words) gem.

```
require 'numbers_and_words'

ruby 2.0.0> 15432.to_words
=> "fifteen thousand four hundred thirty-two"
```

Comment: I try to do like in your example. By IRB - all fine. But when I create file and put there
require 'numbers_and_words'
def Fixnum(w)
w.to_i.to_words
end

Have this error
`require': cannot load such file -- numbers_and_words (LoadError)

Comment: Is IRB using the same ruby as your system?

Comment: I just put require 'numbers_and_words' in my rake file...and all working fine

Comment: This is the problem with such APIs: they have to choose between American English and UK English (i.e. whether to use 'and'). Because of this, this gem is no use to me, but a UK gem would be no use to Americans... I wish there was a gem that had both.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [Linguistics](https://github.com/ged/linguistics) gem. Install with:

```
gem install linguistics
```

And then run:

```
require 'linguistics'
Linguistics.use(:en) #en for english
5.en.numwords #=> "five"
```

This will work for any number you throw at it. It's also worth mentioning that Linguistics only includes a module for English right now, so don't use it if you need i18n.

Comment: @iAmRubuuu: A little digging gets you a long way. Thanks!

Comment: do you aware of this `gem` earlier or jut goggling brings the answer? :D

Comment: @iAmRubuuu: Just googling.

Comment: OMG! I did search, nothing comes out :( what keywords you used in the search tab? It seems I need to learn how to search :(

Comment: @iAmRubuuu: I actually searched something else, got to a Ruby Forumn thread, and got there from here.

Comment: that's called Good Luck :) :)

Comment: @alfasin: Thanks! Take a look at the docs for linguistics -- it can do some other cool things too, like making plurals ('goose' to 'geese'), and a lot of other things.

Comment: ERROR:  Error installing linguistics:
 linguistics requires Ruby version >= 1.9.3.

Comment: @Linuxios I was just looking at https://github.com/ged/linguistics/blob/master/README.rdoc  :)

Comment: @JohnOggy: Or, if your on Windows, the [One Click Installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/).

Answer (score 2):

I remember writing a recursive solution on this. Try it out if dont want to use any gem :).

```
class Integer
  def in_words
    words_hash = {0=>"zero",1=>"one",2=>"two",3=>"three",4=>"four",5=>"five",6=>"six",7=>"seven",8=>"eight",9=>"nine",
                    10=>"ten",11=>"eleven",12=>"twelve",13=>"thirteen",14=>"fourteen",15=>"fifteen",16=>"sixteen",
                     17=>"seventeen", 18=>"eighteen",19=>"nineteen",
                    20=>"twenty",30=>"thirty",40=>"forty",50=>"fifty",60=>"sixty",70=>"seventy",80=>"eighty",90=>"ninety"}

    if words_hash.has_key?(self) 
      words_hash[self]
    elsif self >= 1000
      scale = [""," thousand"," million"," billion"," trillion"," quadrillion"]
      value = self.to_s.reverse.scan(/.{1,3}/)
        .inject([]) { |first_part,second_part| first_part << (second_part == "000" ? "" : second_part.reverse.to_i.in_words) }
      (value.each_with_index.map { |first_part,second_part| first_part == "" ? "" : first_part + scale[second_part] }-[""]).reverse.join(" ")

    elsif self <= 99
       return [words_hash[self - self%10],words_hash[self%10]].join(" ")
    else
      words_hash.merge!({ 100=>"hundred" })
      ([(self%100 < 20 ? self%100 : self.to_s[2].to_i), self.to_s[1].to_i*10, 100, self.to_s[0].to_i]-[0]-[10])
        .reverse.map { |num| words_hash[num] }.join(" ")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: i like the way you performed without using gem.

Answer (score 1):

Search on google for humanize gem or you can just use a hash like this:

```
number_to_word = { 1 => "One", 2 => "Two", 3 => "Three", ...}
```

then access corresponding text like this:

```
text = number_to_word[1] # for accessing value of 1
```

Comment: so, there is not any function in Ruby which do that work for me ?)

Comment: there is no inbuilt function in Ruby for this AFAIK. But you should check out his: https://github.com/radar/humanize

Comment: You're welcome.Please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the tick mark on the left side of this answer :D

Comment: the semicolon at the end of the line is obsolete.

Comment: that's not obsolete but redundant

Comment: Correct. Your English is better than mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
mapper = {0 => "zero", 1 => "one", 2 => "two",... }
# and now you can use mapper to print the text version of a numer
print mapper[2]
```